# AutoDropdown list in expedia "flying from" airport list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need your help, I am trying to select auto dropdown list of airport name under "flying from" in www.Expedia.com. my code is succesfully running but not generating desired output.

Using this line of code i send keys to "flying from"

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='City or airport']")).sendKeys("London");
```

then using this code i am trying to capture heathrow from autodropdown list but instead of London, United Kingdom (LHR-Heathrow) my code select London, United Kingdom (STN-Stansted).

```
        List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements((By.xpath("//div[@class='autocomplete-dropdown']")));
    for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
        if(list.get(i).getText().contains("Heathrow")){
            list.get(i).click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Current Output: London, United Kingdom (SEN-Southend)
Expected Output: London, England, UK (LHR-Heathrow)

Below is my code I am trying to click on autosuggestion

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.List;

public class expedia_search {
public static void main (String args[]) {
    // Set the property for webdriver.chrome.driver to be the location to your local download.
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/vc/IdeaProjects/expedia_search/src/chromedriver");

    // Create new instance of ChromeDriver
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    // And now use this to visit expedia.com
    driver.get("http://www.expedia.com");

    // Find the text input element by its absolute path(xpath)
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tab-flight-tab-hp\"]"));

    // Once flight tab selected click on it
    element.click();

    //type london on Expedia from tab
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='City or airport']")).sendKeys("London");

    //capture auto suggestions from expedia from
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements((By.xpath("//div[@class='autocomplete-dropdown']")));
    for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
        if(list.get(i).getText().contains("Heathrow")){
            list.get(i).click();
            break;
        }
      }

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the xpath you are using to select the value from the dropdown is incorrect. The xpath you are using is of the whole containing of the dropdown, so selenium is clicking on its middle and "STN-Stansted" is getting clicked. You need to use the xpath for the list which is displayed for the dropdown.
 Please use the xpath i am mentioning below:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='results-item']"));
```

Comment: Sameer your answer works correcttly several times i tried to capture Xpath using Chropath but did not get success. if you do not mind would you share how come you know this "//li[@class='results-item']" is correct Xpath? please guide me

Comment: Chropath doesn't always give the perfect xpath when its dealing with complex html structure. I have uploaded a screenshot of the html structure of the autocompleter, where you can see that the className of the results is `results-item` with a tag of `li` corresponding to it and hence i derived the xpath which i have mentioned in the answer. Please check the screenshot here: https://imgur.com/h2rRDV8

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Here is the xpath and css that you can use to select the airport directly without using the loop.

**CSS:**

```
.autocomplete-dropdown a[data-value*='LTN']
```

**xpath:**
   //div[@class='autocomplete-dropdown']//a[contains(@data-value,'Luton')]

Selenium Implementation:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='autocomplete-dropdown']//a[contains(@data-value,'Luton')]")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".autocomplete-dropdown a[data-value*='Luton']")).click();
```